# Extracting words from a paragraph and then match with existing database by Ms Access

Tags: ms-access, extract, matching

I am the beginner on the usage of MS Access.

I am going to build a program in the MS Access 2007 which can scanning some specific wordings listed in the data table from a paragraph.

For example, I want to know the occurrences of the transportation taken by the students.

(i) Therefore, I set the words "school" and "Bus" in my datatable [tableA] fields [trans].

(ii) Then, I input "I go to school by bus." in the [Input] boxes.

(iii) The result i want is that the sun of occurrences of both "school" and "Bus" can be showed in the another one textbox.

In the current situation, i just create a query [QueryA] from the [tableA] and directly use the count function in the query form. And then set the criteria as  " Like [forms]![tableA]![Input] & "*" ".

However, it can just match the words in the [Input] with the final count result of the Query.

Ths a lot for providing any advice, including new direction.

Comment: For supplement, the result i want is that, 

(i) Input "I go to school by bus." in the put box 

(ii) Access scan the words, "school" and "Bus" ("School"&"Bus" is inside the [tableA] with the fields [trans])

 (iii) Another text box show the result of "2" ( School 1 + bus 1)

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand what you're asking here, so I'll give it a stab with the information that you've provided.  In your SQL window, try the following script:  **NOTE: You will need to change the WHERE clause to reflect your Input box(s)**

```
SELECT Count(*) AS Expr1
FROM tableA
WHERE tableA.[trans]  Like '%[Input]%;
```

Comment: Excuse  me, how about counting the target words in a paragraph?
The result i want is that,
(i) Input "I go to school by bus." in the put box
(ii) Access scan the words, "school" and "Bus"
(iii) Another text box show the result of "2" ( School 1 + bus 1)